# how to exclude an element during the binding event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

when iterating over a collection of form elements as shown below is it possible to ignore an element?  I've noticed for a certain scenario the form produces a unique text field which is causing an issue.  im using jquery 1.3.2

http://jsfiddle.net/ewWaF/

if you remove the newfield1 and newfield2 it works from the link above.

many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those fields are display:none you can filter by using the .not() and the :hidden selector

```
$('.PassengerWrapper input[type=text], .PassengerWrapper select').not(":hidden")
```

Here's an update to your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ewWaF/2/

Comment: @JamesRadford Just added an update fiddle to my answer.  Hopefully it will help you find out what you're looking for

Comment: thanks for this, currently being tested.  For the moment, it looks very good.  Many thanks, after testing completes I will update stackoverflow appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You would add the `:not()` selector to your selection:

```
$('.PassengerWrapper input[type=text]:not(selector), .PassengerWrapper select')
```

Or filter it out afterwards:

```
$('.PassengerWrapper input[type=text], .PassengerWrapper select')
    .not("selector")
```

Comment: Or use the `.not()` function, which might be faster.

Comment: the "selector" part means you have to put in a selector that you need.  Not literally use "selector"

Comment: @JamesRadford You need to replace the `"selector"` part of `.not("selector")` with an actual jQuery selector like `'#lastname1'` in your fiddle.

Comment: Correct, the fiddle was not there when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the selection and apply bind to a subset, you should try the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) api of jQuery before the bind chain.